# SQL Server: format default Date Time

Tags: sql-server

I need something that would format the date. I have done this but I am sure I wouldn't need a WITH clause to do this. I know there is an easier way to do this.

Create two columns and format Table6.StartDate to appear as followings
 1 - [dd MonthName yyyy] sample [05 January 2019]
 2- [dd mm yyyy] sample [05 01 2019]

My query

---

```
WITH RESULT AS
    (
    SELECT
        T.CID,
        RTRIM(DAY(T.StartDate)) AS Dayofmon,
        RTRIM(DATENAME(MONTH,T.StartDate)) AS MonthNam,
        RTRIM(YEAR(T.StartDate)) AS Years,
        CONVERT(DATE, t.StartDate ,102) AS conv_MonthName,
        CONVERT(DATE, T.EndDate, 101) AS conv_DDMMYYYY
    FROM temp.dbo.Table6 AS T
    )
SELECT R.CID
    ,StartDate = CONCAT(R.Dayofmon, ' ', R.MonthNam, ' ', R.Years)
    ,R.conv_MonthName
    ,R.conv_DDMMYYYY
FROM RESULT AS R
```

Table create code

```
CREATE TABLE temp.dbo.Table6
(
     CID INT NOT NULL,
     PID INT NOT NULL,
     SSC VARCHAR(3),
     StartDate DATE,
     EndDate DATE, 
     Data VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO temp.dbo.Table1
VALUES
(1001,  1333,   'OP',GETDATE(),GETDATE(),'OP2001156519952012'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR',GETDATE(),NULL,'OR20121005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP',GETDATE(),NULL,'OP20131215'),
(1004,  1234,   'OP',GETDATE(), GETDATE(),'OP2001156519952012')
```

---

sample data

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want to do. Do you want to create a new column with various formats?  Or are you trying to insert a date with one format into a date field with a different format?

Comment: these two formats 1 [6 January 2019] 2-[06 01 2019]. StartDate column is actually a method i used but I am thinking there is an easier way.

Comment: I still don't understand what you want to do.  I understand you have two different formats, but I'm not sure beyond that.  Do you want to create a new column with various formats? Or are you trying to insert a date with one format into a date field with a different format?

Comment: Since it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve I recommend checking this [dates formatting](https://www.sqldates.com/) tool.

Comment: Ty, i needed dateformates thats all, FORMAT(t.StartDate, 'dd MM yyyy') AS New works nice and the other format was the ability to insert Day names and Month names. FORMAT(@your_datetime, 'dddd dd MMMM MMM MM yyyy ddd')

Comment: post that as an answer so I can mark it plz

Comment: Actually, instead of marking an answer, you should probably delete the question.  As written it is too unclear to be of any use to future readers, and an answer that only contains a link to a tool will be useless if the link ever goes dead.   Unless you're both willing to make the effort to make the question clear and the answer useful without the link, you may as well just delete it now that your problem is solved.

Comment: Question edited makes since now :) my bad i misunderstood that my be convert was used to format dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking this [dates formatting tool](https://www.sqldates.com/)
OR `FORMAT(@your_datetime, '%d MMMM yyyy')`